# C: Reading a file to keep track of each extended ASCII appearance count

Tags: c, ascii

I am currently trying to read the count of each character in a file. The file is encrypted so it contains ascii values 0 to 255. My ultimate goal is to return the character that appeared the most.

**The Problem**

After reading through the file I print the array  for debugging purposes. To my surprise the array only counts characters 0 - 127(Not extend character). All indexes past 127 are 0. Sadly the file contains a large amount of extended ascii. I do not know what the problem could be. I believe it would be in my comparsion or data type.

```
char breakKey(FILE * cryFile, int keyLength) {
    fseek(cryFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
    unsigned int count[256] = {0};
    char ch;
    int c = 0;
    while((ch = fgetc(cryFile)) != EOF){
        for(int i = 0; i < 255 ; i++){
            if(i == (int) ch) {
                count[i]++;             
            }   
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 255 ; i++){
        printf("%d : %d \n", i, count[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ASCII does only have 7 bits. There are many codes which use additionally the upper 128 codes in a octet. Problem is one of the most common is UTF-8 (a Uincode encoding) which does use the 8th bit to signal multi-byte characters which allows to encode all Unicode characters (currently about 1Mio - actually 2**20).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The character `ch` can be signed or unsigned, according to the implementation.  In your testing, it is apparently signed.  Making it an `int` is standard practice, because `EOF` is a negative value which cannot be a character.

Along those lines, the loop to match the character against the array index is not effective.  All you need to do is

```
count[(unsigned char)ch]++;
```

rather than

```
for(int i = 0; i < 255 ; i++){
    if(i == (int) ch) {
        count[i]++;             
    }   
}
```

Comment: Why not use `unsigned` instead of `int`? I think it is bad practice to cast an unsigned type to a signed without actual need. Also this would state clear the index will not be negative.

Comment: If you use `unsigned`, the comparison against `EOF` will fail, without a cast.

Comment: Just had a look at your answer, forgot to check code in the question. However, as `fgetc()` does return int which is casted to char (be it signed or unsigned). The comparision will be wrong anyway: if `char` is unsigned, `i` gets a value of 255 after the double conversion. If char is signed, i gets a negative value for any value above 127 returned by fgets, so any non-ASCII code will yield a negative index. The only correct way would be to have ch being `int` and after EOF-test cast it to an unsigned whatever - `unsigned char` might be appropriate, but `size_t` would be the correct choice.

Comment: Point is: `char` cannot represent all possible results of `fgetc()` (the signed-ness does not increase the possible codes). That's why it returns int, which has at least 16 bits. All "successfull" results, however, do fit into a char. Its signed-ness does not care unless doing arithmetics with it. Indexing is actually (pointer-)arithmetic.